# finding the index of the same letter in a string

Tags: python, jython

Currently working with

```py
def order(word):
  for each in word:
    print str(word.index(each))+ ": "+each
```

If I run `order("Ranger")`, the code works as I want to and it gives me:

```
0: R
1: a
2: n
....and so on until "5: r"
```

but if I put in any word with repeating letters like "hall" or "silicon," I get the position value of the first iteration of the word such as:

```py
order("Hall")
0: H
1: a
2: l
2: l
```

How can I get the the function to return the following?

```py
0: H
1: a
2: l
3: l
```

Comment: You would also have similar "wrong" output with `order("ranger")` - `'R' != 'r'`. Your issue is that you don't specify the starting location to find the character within the text, so it finds the first instance.

Comment: `index()` returns the lowest index only (you can specify a start parameter though), it also iterate the same word once for each letter which is unnecessary, so use a for loop on enumerate(word).

Answer (score 6):

[`str.index()`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html#str.index) just returns the lowest index of the substring.

You can just [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate) a string for your purposes:

```
def order(word):
    for index, letter in enumerate(word):
        print('{}: {}'.format(index,letter))
```

Also, please consider using python 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged this as Python here is a Python implementation.

```
def order(word):
  for i in range(len(word)):
    print(i+1, ":", word[i])
order("hall")
```

I am basically iterating through the length of the word and am printing out the character at that position. In your case, str.index() prints out the first occurrence of the character. Hope this helped.